# extract excel data via sql; date column not working

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access

I am using the function below to extract data from another workbook. It works for non-Date columns, but does not work for a column which holds dates

Worksheet looks like

[image]

Works if is **not a date column**:

```vb
Debug.Print GetSheetSQL(workbookPath, "Select columna from [sheet$]")(1)("columna")
```

--> Returns "palim"

Does not work if a is a **date column**

```vb
Debug.Print GetSheetSQL(workbookPath, "Select columnb from [sheet$]")(1)("columnb")
```

--> Returns Nothing

```vb
Function GetSheetSQL(path As String, sqlStr As String) As Collection

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Open ADOB Connection and query via sql
'   Connection string is standard and
'   taken from:
'        https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/standard-excel/

Dim objConnection As Object
Dim objRecordSet As Object
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & path & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"""

objRecordSet.Open sqlStr, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Iterate through queried table
'   table is a collection with a row per row in the table
'   row is a dictionary with table headings as key, returning the corresponding value
Dim table As Collection
Set table = New Collection
Dim row As Object
Dim fld
'iterate through recordset rows
Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
    With objRecordSet
        Set row = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        For Each fld In .Fields
            row.Add fld.Name, fld.Value
        Next fld

        table.Add row

        .MoveNext

    End With
Loop

Set GetSheetSQL = table

'Close Connection; reset Error Handling to default
objConnection.Close
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function
ErrorCloseConn:
    objConnection.Close
    On Error GoTo 0
    Resume
End Function
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine for me. What do you mean with `Returns Nothing`?

Comment: Your SQL statement is missing a few quotation marks -- `"Select ... [sheet$]"`

Comment: Sorry I do have those in the original stmt. I'll change that

Comment: @Storax it returns the string "NULL" although I am sure there is sth in that row or sometimes just ""

Comment: I could reproduce your problem. Is it possible that one of your date fields is actually text. At least that's the way I was able to reproduce the issue. In this case ADODB will just ignore the content of the cell in excel.

Comment: It is a custom in German "benutzerdefiniert" formatted cell

Comment: @Storax You mean one of the values in the date field? and the other is indeed a date, which confuses Excel? Otherwise, why doesn't ADODB interpret it as a text field?

Comment: Check if the first character is `'`.

Comment: @Zev Spitz: Yes, on of the values in the date field is text and the other are dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to re-produce the issue, maybe this is of help

[image]

This looks fine but I changed the first cell with a date to text. Debugging the code will give you

[image]

So, ADODB expects a date, Type is adDate and converts text to an empty string.

> **The following update solved the problem in the end**

**UPDATE** It might help to change the connection string to

```
objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & path & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"""
```

For further information look [here](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/509360)

Comment: Does this affect all the rows? Or only the row with the text data in it?

Comment: For me it says adVarWChar. I formatted all cells to text, but the issue persists. I do have some empty cells in the date column. Could that be the issue? Thanks a lot for helping me!!!

Comment: I also formatted all cells to text then I also get the data type adVarWChar but I also get a result

Comment: Then the issue is somewhere with my data  :/

Comment: Maybe but you could also try to change the import mode

Comment: where do I change the import Mode? Or do you mean not using SQL at all?

Comment: In the connection string

Comment: @PalimPalim Will formatting as text change the data type? Don't you have to change the value of the cell by starting it with a `'` in order for it to actually be text?

Comment: Didn't see your update but ended up with the same solution IMEX=1 solves all my issues, no need to format or anything. Cheers man!